# How to start DOS on a PC with just HDD (no FDD/CD/USB drives)

Tags: partitioning, floppy, disk-operating-system

Would making a first partition (which FAT?) of 1,44 MB with a bootable image of DOS start the system on a laptop's HDD? or in other words Can one start a laptop without FDD/CD/USB with just partitioning/ formating /saving on its HDD (using a USB/pata adaptor connected to a second PC then puting it back in the laptop)?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand, but:
If you can format the laptop's HDD. Then

```
Format /S
```

will add the boot sector.
You also can use the the DOS command

```
Sys C:
```

If the HDD has a partition

Answer (score 1):

Just connect the laptop's hard disk as the only disk on another computer that has a CD, then install whatever operating system you like.

Just beware that if you install and activate Windows, then transplanting the hard disk into another machine will invalidate the activation.

Comment: That's why you generalize it before you move it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org). It has fairly up-to-date drivers for modern hardware and instructions for installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've never just copied the disk image from a floppy to the first 1.44MB's worth of sectors on an HDD.  I have a feeling it wouldn't work.  Here's a procedure that will certainly work, as long as your floppy image is DOS 6.22:

- You need to create a FAT16 partition within the first 2GBytes of disk.  True DOS 6.22 can only deal with disks/partitions up to this size, I believe.  Earlier DOS versions had lower limitations (e.g. DOS 3.3 can only deal with disks up to 32MB in size).  The partition must be marked "Active."  Under a DOS system you'd use the `fdisk` utility to accomplish this.
- You need to take sector 0 from the floppy image and copy it to the HDD's sector 0.  The `sys` command will do this, but unfortunately only under DOS.  You can use Linux's `dd` command if you have a Linux system handy, or use `HxD` or similar utility under Windows.
- Last, copy all the files from the floppy image to the hard drive partition.  However, FIRST copy `MSDOS.SYS` and `IO.SYS` into the root of the partition.  Then copy everything else.